# How to dynamically create widgets in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am developng a MCQ app  in kivy which has 2 questions and associated options. I have used labels for questions and labels and checkboxes for answers in my app.

The code is working fine. However, the issue is now the app has only 2 questions so its Ok. Suppose, if the app has some hundred questions, the method I used will be too tedious and may not be that efficient. There should be a way where I can **create dynamic widgets using less number of code lines**. Kindly suggest an alternative where I can create dynamic widgets and improve my code

My code:

tut13.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.lang import Builder

class Scroll_2(ScrollView):
    pass


class Demo_12(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("kv\Design11.kv")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Demo_12().run()
```

Design11.ky

```
<Mygrid@GridLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.52, 0.8, 1, 1

        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    size_hint: 0.95, None
    pos_hint: {'x': 0.025}
    height: 200
    padding: 20

<Mycheck@CheckBox>:
    canvas.before:           
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x-8, self.center_y-8
            size: 16, 16
    color: 1, 1, 0, 1            

<Mylabel@ButtonBehavior+Label>:
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    font_size: 18
    bold: True

Scroll_2:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        spacing: 20

        Mygrid:
            cols: 1 

            Mylabel: 
                text: 'Question1'                

            BoxLayout:
                Mycheck:
                    id: q1opt1cb1
                    on_press: if self.active: print(q1opt1.text)

                Mylabel:
                    id: q1opt1
                    text: 'Option 1'
                    on_press: 
                        q1opt1cb1._do_press()
                        if q1opt1cb1.active: print(self.text)

                Mycheck:
                    id: q1opt1cb2
                    on_press: if self.active: print(q1opt2.text)

                Mylabel:
                    id: q1opt2
                    text: 'Option 2'
                    on_press: 
                        q1opt1cb2._do_press()
                        if q1opt1cb2.active: print(self.text)

                Mycheck:
                    id: q1opt1cb3
                    on_press: if self.active: print(q1opt3.text)

                Mylabel:
                    id: q1opt3
                    text: 'Option 3'
                    on_press: 
                        q1opt1cb3._do_press()
                        if q1opt1cb3.active: print(self.text)


        Mygrid:
            cols: 1 

            Mylabel: 
                text: 'Question2'                

            BoxLayout:
                Mycheck:
                    id: q2opt1cb1
                    on_press: if self.active: print(q2opt1.text)

                Mylabel:
                    id: q2opt1
                    text: 'Option 1a'
                    on_press: 
                        q2opt1cb1._do_press()
                        if q2opt1cb1.active: print(self.text)

                Mycheck:
                    id: q2opt1cb2
                    on_press: if self.active: print(q2opt2.text)

                Mylabel:
                    id: q2opt2
                    text: 'Option 2a'
                    on_press: 
                        q2opt1cb2._do_press()
                        if q2opt1cb2.active: print(self.text)

                Mycheck:
                    id: q2opt1cb3
                    on_press: if self.active: print(q2opt3.text)

                Mylabel:
                    id: q2opt3
                    text: 'Option 3a'
                    on_press: 
                        q2opt1cb3._do_press()
                        if q2opt1cb3.active: print(self.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this will help:

The .py code

```py
class Scroll_2(ScrollView):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Scroll_2, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.setup_questions()

    def setup_questions(self):
        data = [["Question 1", ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]],
                ["Question 2", ["Option 1", "Option 2"]],
                ["Question 3", ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"]],
                ["Question 4", ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]],
                ]
        for i in data:
            question = MyGrid(q_text=i[0])
            for j in i[1]:
                question.ids.o_box.add_widget(Option(text=j))
            self.ids.q_box.add_widget(question)

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    q_text = StringProperty()


class Option(BoxLayout):
    text = StringProperty()

class Demo_12(App):

    def build(self):
        return Scroll_2()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Demo_12().run()
```

and the .kv code

```
<Mycheck@CheckBox>:
    canvas.before:           
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x-8, self.center_y-8
            size: 16, 16
    color: 1, 1, 0, 1            

<Mylabel@ButtonBehavior+Label>:
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    font_size: 18
    bold: True

<Scroll_2>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: q_box
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        spacing: 20

<Option>:
    Mycheck:
        id: opt1cb1
        on_press: if self.active: print(root.text)
    Mylabel:
        text: root.text
        on_press: 
            opt1cb1._do_press()
            if opt1cb1.active: print(self.text)

<MyGrid>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.52, 0.8, 1, 1

        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    size_hint: 0.95, None
    pos_hint: {'x': 0.025}
    height: 200
    padding: 20
    cols: 1
    Mylabel: 
        text: root.q_text
    BoxLayout:
        id: o_box
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.. kindly suggest if I have to make the options also dynamic, how can I do it..I mean some questions might have only 2 options and some questions might have more than 2 questions..

Comment: @Pavan I think that it will need a different approach. You can create a new question to post some new code..

Comment: @Pavan BTW, how can you have more than two questions with one set of options?

Comment: no no I meant for each question options may vary...for example question 1 might have only 2 options, question 2 might have 4 options and so on....instead of having static 3 options for all questions, I want to dynamically add set of options for each question..overall questions are also added dynamically and for each question, options are also added dynamically..kindly suggest an alternative .. thanks

Comment: @Pavan I was asking because you wrote "...and some questions might have more than 2 questions..". Anyway, it is doable, but needs some more code that I cannot post in a comment. Also, I don't think we must pollute your original question/answer here. That's why I asked you to create a new question. Tomorrow I'll write the code, and if there is no new question I'll post you a gist..